# Python/Django - Bytes back to string

Tags: python, django

I´m getting a file that the user uploads this way:

```
if request.method == "POST":
    data = request.FILES['some_file']

    lines = data.readlines()
```

I´m reading the lines from the txt file that is uploaded. The thing is that i have a lot of methods taking in count that the 'lines' in this file are strings. For example:

```
def search_date(lines):
    lista = [line.split(",", 1)[0] for line in lines]
```

The problem is that the readlines() returns bytes:

[image]

I tried to decoded back to utf-8 but with no luck. I really need this to be a string.
Now i am getting:

```
'str' does not support the buffer interface
```

Thanks in advance for any help provided

Comment: Can you post the full stack trace? The `lines` should already been a list of `str` because `str` is a string of bytes. When you decode, you turned `str` into `unicode`. Also, are you using python3?

Comment: Yes @ShangWang its python 3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
def search_date(lines):
    lista = [line.decode('utf8').split(",", 1)[0] for line in lines]
```